# Views result sorting using arguments

Tags: views

Is there any option available in Drupal views to sort views result using the arguments provided (contextual filters)

I am trying to integrate a search functionality using views. My problem is that contextual filter will list only matching results, I need all the results but it should sort according to the arguments passed using contextual filters. Is that possible?

I.E.   I pass the following string to a contextual NID argument:
1099+1100+1102+1098+1101+1097

I expect the order of the nodes in the view to be the same as the order as passed in through the argument.

Comment: can you give any explanation??

Comment: Suppose we are listing node tiles using views and if we give node id in contextual filters it will filter the results and show the title corresponding to the node id we passed.  Like that I need to sort the result according to the argument i.e. matching results should list first following unmatched results.

Comment: can't you give the same field in sorting.

Comment: I am trying to integrate a search functionality using views. My problem is that contextual filter will list only matching results, but i need all the results but it should sort according to the matching results. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

This is what helped for me.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2474164/28672

Using the second option to generate the view manually then modifying the array in the result property.

And this is the code I used to sort the results to the argument

```
 // Sort the view based on the argument now we've generated it.
  $results = $view->result;
  $view_argument_array = explode('+', '1099+1100+1102+1098+1101+1097');
  $new_result_order = array();
  foreach ($view_argument_array as $nid) {
    foreach ($results as $result) {
      if ($result->nid == $nid) {
        $new_result_order[] = $result;
      }
    }
  }
  $view->result = $new_result_order;
```